# JIRA Api for 'Find users with browse permission ' not working

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am trying to get a list of users who have access to a particular issue.

I tried using  **GET /rest/api/2/user/viewissue/search** for this . But it asks for username and issueKey query parameters. Also it is returning only one user.

How does this api work? 
I refered to the documentation here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-user-viewissue-search-get

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT to the below: If you query with username=% (i.e. a wildcard) then it returns
> every user with permission

As the documentation you've linked to states, you do need to provide an issueKey and a username or it won't return any results:

> username
>
> string
>
> the username filter, no users returned if left blank

This is saying, find all the users who have permission to see the specified issue, where their username matches this specific filter value I'm providing, i.e. not all users that have permission.

It's filtering on some combination of username, display name and email (I think).

I have a JIRA Cloud site with three users:

- admin, which has a display name of Mike Jones and an email of mike.jones@...
- mike, which has a display name of Mike Jones and an email of mike.jones@...
- mike.jones, which has a display name of Mike Smith and an email of mike.jones@...

If I run this query, I see all three users returned:

```
https://<url>/rest/api/2/user/viewissue/search?issueKey=DD-1&username=mike
```

If I change the last query parameter to be username=smith then I see just the third user with a display name of Mike Smith, which suggests it's querying the Display Name field:

```
https://<url>/rest/api/2/user/viewissue/search?issueKey=DD-1&username=smith
```

But if I use the parameter username=jones, then I see all three users, which suggests it's querying the Email field:

```
https://<url>/rest/api/2/user/viewissue/search?issueKey=DD-1&username=jones
```

And if I use the parameter username=admin, then I only see the admin user, which suggests it's querying on the Username field:

```
https://<url>/rest/api/2/user/viewissue/search?issueKey=DD-1&username=admin
```